# Centering a wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, css-float, wordpress-theming

I am running a friend's Wordpress with the Gridly theme. He asked me to center the website.

I've done most of it, but i'm stuck at centering the menu. I think it might be because the CSS tells it to float:left. I'm not sure though.

Here is a link : [www.krenaud.fr](http://krenaud.fr)

Answer (score 1):

In `light.css` file on line number 31 make `width:770px` insted of 100% and add `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: Thank you for this fix. However, even though the menu is now in a 770px box in the center, the menu itself is not in the center of that box. Would you have a solution to this as well ?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest option seems to be setting the menu container to:

```
.menu-menu-principal-container {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Looks like that should work to center the menu.